# findByIdAndUpdate is not adding new fields into database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My model in Mongoose has about 20-30 attributes in it, however I am in development and am only using about 5 for now. There is an edit page that can edit existing information but it will not 'insert' one of the attributes already in the model. I am guessing that `findByIdAndUpdate` only changes existing values, where is there a good guide as to what other methods Mongoose has, and actually explains them well!

Here is my route:

```
    router.put("/event/:id", isLoggedIn, function (req,res) {
   Event.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body.editEvent, function (err, updatedEvent) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("/event");
        } else {
            console.log("This is the updated Event");
            console.log(updatedEvent);
            console.log("done with updated event");
            res.redirect("/event/" + req.params.id);
        }

    })
    });
```

Comment: Make sure to select the helpful answer which was helped you

Answer (score 1):

For example I can suggest the following:

```
router.post('/save-some-data-to-model', function(req, res, next) {
    User.findOne({
        field: value
    }, function(err, user) {
        user.name = req.body.name

        user.save(function(err) {
            if (err) return next(err)
        })
})
```

This code find one user document in `User` collection by some `field`, next save `req.body.name` (from form input with `name="name"` attribute) and save it to MongoDB using `save()`

In addition:

HTML Form

```
<form method="post" action="/save-some-data-to-model">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name: </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name">
    </div>
</form>
```

Note:

If you are using Express.js you need to install `body-parser` and enable it as middleware like this

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `$set` operator in your mongoose command.

Try this:

```
router.put("/event/:id", isLoggedIn, function (req,res) {
   Event.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {"$set": req.body.editEvent}, function (err, updatedEvent) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("/event");
        } else {
            console.log("This is the updated Event");
            console.log(updatedEvent);
            console.log("done with updated event");
            res.redirect("/event/" + req.params.id);
        }

    })
});
```

This should be useful as a reference:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/

> Behavior
>
> If the field does not exist, $set will add a new field with the
>   specified value, provided that the new field does not violate a type
>   constraint. If you specify a dotted path for a non-existent field,
>   $set will create the embedded documents as needed to fulfill the
>   dotted path to the field.

Comment: Hmm. Try the updated code, I changed `"$set": {req.body.editEvent}` to `"$set": req.body.editEvent`.